# What is android:configChanges="0x480" in an Android Manifest?

Tags: android, android-manifest

Recently found this in an Android Manifest:

```
<activity [...] android:configChanges="0x480">
```

What does that mean?

Comment: Are you looking at a decompiled manifest? That's the resultant value of some combination of the flags available for that attribute: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#config. I'm not sure if there's a docs or dev page with the actual numerical values, but your IDE will tell you, or you can check the source: [`attrs_manifest.xml`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/values/attrs_manifest.xml#967). Looks like `orientation|screenSize`, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

As Mike M explained the decompiled hex value "0x480" could be anything (orientation|screenSize|density|...).
Are you trying to reverse engineer the original values set in the AndroidManifest.xml?